# Dump STDOUT into file-specific nohup.out files

Tags: makefile, stdout, nohup

Suppose you have a simple makefile which consists of a pattern rule such as:

```
all: 1_end.fa 2_end.fa 3_end.fa

%_end.fa: %_start.fa
 program $^ > $@
```

When you run such a makefile with nohup, the STDOUT from each process is dumped into the same nohup.out file. Is it possible to create a rule where the STDOUT from each process is dumped into its own file-specific nohup.out file?

**Update 1:**

I have managed to work this out, but I'm still open for better suggestions. My method uses a sister makefile to run the pipeline makefile, passing a command line variable to the processes and renaming the nohup on running. Such as:

**pipeline.GNUmakefile:**

```
all: $(source)_end.fa

$(source)_end.fa: $(source)_start.fa
 program $^ > $'
```

**config.GNUmakefile:**

```
sources = $(wildcard *.fa)

nohups = $(sources.fa=.out)

all: $(nohups)

%.out: %.fa
 nohup make -f pipeline.GNUmakefile source=$(basename $^) > $@ &
```

Comment: Your solution has a race condition when run with parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

For each source, create a temporary directory, `cd` there, run `nohup` from there, rename the output file from there to whatever you want, delete the temporary directory.

Really has nothing to do with makefiles.